# Unable to see the json data after chaining the cy.visit()

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

After login to a site, I have given two urls, first I should be visiting the first url and then approx waiting for around 20 seconds, then I should be visiting the second url.
After that I should see some json data displaying in site. If we didn't wait for 20 seconds I won't be getting the json data.  I have tried below, but not able to see the json data. What else should I do to see that data ?

`cypress version : 6.1.0`

`cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`

`LoadJSON.feature`

```
Feature: LoadJson Data

    Scenario: Access url
        Given I open the build URL
        
    Scenario: Login and see JSON DATA
        Given I am logged in as Cypress user
        When I send a awesome request to site to json data
```

first url : https://somedomain.com/student/add/generateSomeStatements.php

second url: https://somedomain.com/student/readInstructions.php

`Step definitions`

```
/* Login step */ 
When('I am logged in as Cypress user', () => {
  cy.get('[name=Username]').type(Cypress.env('USERNAME'));
  cy.get('[name=Password]').type(Cypress.env('PASSWORD'), { sensitive: true });
  cy.contains('Login').click();
})

/* Load JSON data step*/ 
And('I send a awesome request to site to json data', () => {
    cy.visit('add/generateSomeStatements.php')
      .wait(25000)
      .then(
          async () => await cy.visit('readInstructions.php').then((resp)=>{
            console.log(resp);
        })
      )
    
});
```

Comment: I wonder if it is better to `cy.request('add/generateSomeStatements.php').then(() => wait and then visit)`.

Comment: @RichardMatsen. Sorry I have tried that earlier with `cy.request()`. In both cases just a white screen appears.

Comment: After login if we manually type the url `add/generateSomeStatements.php` and wait for 20 seconds and then type the next url  `readInstructions.php'` I am able to see the json data. But when I do it via cypress, just a white screen.

Comment: Sounds difficult. I am guessing it's not public facing to try? Another idea, is it related to login cookies (`Cookies.preserveOnce()`)?

Comment: Why do both `async () => await` and `.then()` on the one line? They are alternative ways to wait, probably causing a problem.  `async () => await` before a visit is actually weird, since `cy.visit()` returns a Cypress chainer, not a promise.

Comment: @RichardMatsen Yes, that is right, its not public facing to give try. Will try that preserving cookies.

Comment: @MarionMorrison I have removed the `async () => await` and ``then`` from visit..

Comment: but no difference yet.

Comment: Why remove both?

Comment: I was trying to see will that make any difference...``cy.visit('add/generateSomeStatements.php')
      .wait(25000)
      .then(
            cy.visit('readInstructions.php')
      )``